# Booting from USB, Install Ubuntu. Debian used to download

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I would like to install Ubuntu onto computer 2 computer 1 is Debian.

1. Where to get Ubuntu from.
2. How to put a ISO file onto a bookable USB
3. how to install Ubuntu

I am new.

Comment: Did you try looking at the various tutorials?  You didn't specify which Ubuntu product you're asking about (Server? Core? or Desktop?) but you can try before installing (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)  with many tutorials availble - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1-overview
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/14022

Comment: ie. tutorials to write the ISO if you're using MacOS, windows or GNU?Linux (Debian & Ubuntu are very similar).  I use the same commands/apps to write an ISO on Debian as I do if using Ubuntu..  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview (*You may just need to ensure your Debian system is modern & not old. If you're cloning the ISO to thumb-drive you won't have issues, but if not cloned you need updates*)

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER 1**

Official website of Ubuntu should be the priority to download the iso files of your desired Ubuntu versions. here are couple of latest Ubuntu versions

[Ubuntu 22.04(LTS)](https://repo.extreme-ix.org/ubuntu-releases/22.04.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)

[Ubuntu 22.10](https://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu-releases/22.10/ubuntu-22.10-desktop-amd64.iso)

**ANSWER 2**

GUI softwares like  **rufus** (for windows or MAC) and **Unetbootin** (for Linux) are good choices to make your usb drive bootable.
Though we can format the USB drive from terminal (Linux and MAC).
Formatting it with Terminal is a better way as that makes the bootable drive more accurate and errorless.

**ANSWER 3**

Plugging in your bootable USB and choosing your USB partition as your boot option will send you to ubuntu installation

Comment: You mention the official website for downloads; but then use other links?  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ is the official Ubuntu ISO site, but I don't if the sites you gave are even *official mirrors* (ie. exist on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors) or not as I didn't check - but they are not Official Ubuntu download sites.

Comment: The first you list appears to be https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/repo.extreme-ix.org-release  or a Ubuntu mirror; either way that's not from the official Ubuntu website, ie. not https://ubuntu.com/download etc.

Comment: My colleague and I have redacted your contact details from your post. Best to keep personal details like this private...